# Correct way of attaching 'disclose' (or any other) event handler in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

In my simple application I'm listening for the `disclose` event like this :

In the `NotesList.js` (view) file...

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.view.NotesList", {
    extend : "Ext.dataview.List",
    xtype : "noteslist",
    ...
    config : {
       onItemDisclosure : true,       //adds the disclose arrow
    }
});
```

NotesList is used in NotesListContainer which is an `Ext.Container`.

Then in `NotesListContainer.js` (view) ...

```
    var notesList = {
        xtype : "noteslist",
        ...
        listeneres : {
            disclose : { fn : this.onNotesListDisclose, scope : this  }
        }
    };

     this.add([topToolbar, notesList]);
```

The function does this :

```
onNotesListDisclose : function(list, record, target, index, evt, options) {
    console.log(' onNotesListDisclose() called'); //nevers gets logged
    this.fireEvent('editNoteCommand', this, record);
}
```

Then in `Notes.js` (controller) :

```
 refs : {
      //get elemets using xtype attr
      notesListContainer : "noteslistcontainer",
      noteEditor : "noteeditor"
  },
  //handlers for events
  control : {
     //define which events should this controller respond to

     notesListContainer : {
         //events fired by NotesListContainer
         newNoteCommand : "onNewNoteCommand",
         editNoteCommand : "onEditNoteCommand"
     }
  }
},
//Event/Command handler

onEditNoteCommand : function(list, record) {
    console.log(' onEditNoteCommand called ');
    this.activateNoteEditor(record);
}
```

I think the problem is in NotesListContainer.js where I am instantiating the list. 
If I listen for the event in controller like this :

```
refs : {
      //get elemets using xtype attr
      notesListContainer : "noteslistcontainer",
      notesList : "noteslistcontainer list",
  },
  //handlers for events
  control : {
     //define which events should this controller respond to
     notesListContainer : {
         //events fired by NotesListContainer
         newNoteCommand : "onNewNoteCommand",
         //editNoteCommand : "onEditNoteCommand"
     },
     notesList : {
         disclose : "onEditNoteCommand"  //adding it this way works...
     }
  }
```

It works just fine. However, I would prefer to work with a more application specific event instead of very generic `disclose` event.
I am new to sencha touch, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have your own custom business logic driven events, do the following:

- Subscribe to necessary UI events in your main controller
- Generate application wide business events
- Subscribe to these events in your view controller

Comment: Thanks, could you spot the reason why above code is not working as expected i.e. 'onEditNoteCommand' method never gets called.

Comment: you still need to subscribe to generic 'disclose' event. there is no way around it. Inside the handler however you can do something simple like `this.getParent().fireEvent('editItem')` - this way you generate your own editItem event on the container level.

Comment: This is what I am doing. You can see in code second and third code fragment. But the control never reaches `onNotesListDisclose` (in the third code fragment)

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand. But I would recommend in the view raise different event this.fireEvent('newNote'), and then in _controller_ subscribe to this view event.

Answer (score 0):

what you mean with 'a more application specific event'?

The disclose event is a list-component specific one:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-disclose

Comment: for example, 'onEditNoteCommand' makes more sense than 'disclose'